# Autopopulate text field based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I wanted to populate my text field information based on dropdown value.

```
<cfselect  name="Env" width="180"  >
<cfoutput>
 <option value=""  >Select</option>
<option value="prod"  >Production</option>
<option value="beta"  >Beta</option>
 </cfoutput>
</cfselect>
<cfinput 
<cfinput name="ReqNumber" type="text" value="" width="90" >
```

Requestnumber textfield should be displayed automatically like this 
Prod-110611 (env field value - currnet day month year) if user selects prod
and following value should be displayed beta-110611 if user selcts beta from dropdown.

Comment: Where do the numbers `110611` come from?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. We need to display in text field like this.. prod-seqno-06112011 (Seq number comes from cfquery.. like select Myseq.nextval from dual) if user selects prod (if they select beta then it would be beta-seqno-06112011

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I think that the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:text[name="reqNumber"]')
            .val($('select[name="Env"] option:first').val() + '-110611');

        $('select[name="Env"]').change(
            function(){
                $('input:text[name="reqNumber"]').val($(this).val() + '-110611');
            });
    });
```

References:

- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: We need to display in text field like this.. prod-seqno-06112011 (Seq number comes from cfquery.. like select Myseq.nextval from dual) if user selects prod (if they select beta then it would be beta-seqno-06112011 . Thanks in advance.